WCF client configuration with two certificates
I have basic Soap wcf experience and I need to set quite complex WCF client security configuration which uses separate x.509 certificates:

first with private key to sign outgoing message and to decrypt incomming message
second without key to encrypt outgoing message and verify incomming message signature
(incomming/outgoing is from client perspective)

Both certs are already added to client cert store (including root cert for one with private key)
Best if I could also define encoding and signature algorithms
I suppose that is not supported in WCF ws-security standard configuration so I need custom binding?
I follow the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-use-separate-x-509-certificates-for-signing-and-encryption
but that implementation requires duplex binding (or I misunderstood that) which is not required in my case (client endpoint is not allowed), probably given example needs some modification that I can't figure out.
In other words I need to translate into WCF what I could click in SoapUI ws-security configuration (using java keystore file) and select that setting when executing request
SoapUI ws-security service conf
I appreciate any hint
I copied code from that microsoft docs but as mentioned I can't and should not add client endpoint "HTTP could not register URL http://+..Your process does not have rights", I also don't know hot to define algorithms in wcf line ones in soapui.
